# what is the difference between Group and union (pathfinder)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

i want to know  when i should use 'group' (ctrl+G)  and union from pathfinder. i think They are producing same thing .Is there any particular reason for creating two process/command which produce same result?

I want to create a sun burst figure(1) so which command i should apply?[image]
Grouping it or union from pathfinder?

Comment: Why do you need to use Union to create a sun burst?

Comment: please billy dnt ask me. if i know the answer i would nt have asked here. am so confused about illustrator.

Comment: just tell me what is the right thing to do here... am so confused.

Comment: I don't know what the right thing to do would be because I don't know what you want to do with it.   That's why I asked. There are some cases where a union could be needed, and others where making a group would suffice.

Comment: I dnt mind your asking. you know way too better than me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... neither?

To create a sunburst you can just use a circle and modify the stroke to be dashed...

Adjust the Dashed Line dash + gap to increase / reduce the number of "rays".

[image]

Comment: oh my god!!!!! what i just watched! amazing! thankyou so much

Answer (score 2):

When you make a *group* you make a container which holds together the selected objects. The individual objects can still have separate appearance and they can be moved around. You can later choose to *ungroup* to revert to individual objects.

[image]

When you use *unite* from pathfinder you combine the selected objects to one vector object. The individual parts can't have their own appearance and they can't be moved separately anymore. This action can't be reverted later.

[image]

When to choose one or the other is hard to say. It depends on the task at hand. I would say that if you can avoid uniting it leaves your artwork more editable, so I in this case I would probably just choose to group.

Comment: Thank you so much. you are a life saver!